# How to set error message on VBA if item is not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display an error message of invalid number if an element is not found from one sheet to the next.

```
Sub info()

Dim dehyp As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim wrong As String
wrong = "False"

dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
Sheets("Gov").Select

Set rng = Sheets("Gov").Columns(1).Find(What:=dehyp, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
On Error Resume Next
Set wrong = "True"

If wrong = "True" Then
Sheets("Total usage").Select
MsgBox ("Invalid Number")

Else
rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Total usage").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'this part works without the else and the error stuff



End If



End Sub
```

I have defined the dimensions of the variables and set the initial variable wrong to be false. I am getting an compilation error that says an object is required. So my question is why is that happening and what could I do to fix the error?

Comment: `Wrong` variable is a string variable. You don't have to set it. `Set` means VBA expects a range object, which there isn't (hence the first compile error) But I'm wondering if you not looking for a boolean variable and assign it `TRUE` without the double quotes (not went through your code to check if this is what you want). I do see a lot of `.Select` which you can avoid.

Comment: What line is the error and what exactly is the run-time error you're getting?

Comment: I guess the compilation error is due to `Set wrong = "True"`: change it to `wrong = "True"`, but only if you need to set that variable to "True" (which makes subsequent `If wrong = "True" Then` a redundant check...)

Comment: @DisplayName I thought wrong would only = True if there was an error?

Comment: Why is `wrong` declared `As String` and assigned to string-literal values `"True`"/`"False"`, instead of `As Boolean` and assignd with Boolean-literal values `True`/`False`? Also even without the `Set` (which you should only use for *object reference* assignments), `wrong = "True"` can only ever evaluate to `True`, because the variable is assigned to `"True"` *on the instruction that immediately precedes the check*... ...and then, ...that check isn't needed ;-)

Comment: To further @JvdV's comment, instead I'd do `dim wrong as Boolean`, then `wrong = True`.  That way you can just do `if not Wrong then ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standing all the comments, I guess you may be after this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub info()

    Dim dehyp As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
    Set rng = Sheets("Gov").Columns(1).Find(What:=dehyp, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid Number")
    Else
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Total usage").Range("B5")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted! Only thing I wonder is if OP would want to use copy paste (for format reasons) or can just do without

Comment: @JvdV, feel free to enhance the answer

Comment: No, it's absolutely fine as is. It's more like a note to OP that if not needed copy/paste can be avoided.